# Arch installation and swap partition

Tags: arch-linux, swap, storage, kernel-panic

to install Arch on a PC I have to make partition of the HDD

- boot
- swap
- /

The swap is used by virtual memory, right?
What's up if I make a too small or a too big swap partition? Could I have as result some kernel panic?

Comment: You don't *have* to have a swap partition.  You could use a swap file instead (or even no swap at all).  For that matter, you don't even have to have a separate boot partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need the swap partition and the /boot partition.

But returning to your question: yes, the swap is used as virtual memory (and also for hibernation). If both the swap file and the physical RAM fill up, you most likely won't have a kernel panic: applications will just start to be killed by the kernel's [out-of-memory killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/).

But at this point your system will be unbearably slow (which might lead you to think that it has crashed) due to the heavy swapping.

If you have a too-big swap partition, it just won't be used and will be wasted disk space.

Comment: swap is also used for hibernation by default.